# C# XNA Normals, Diffuse, and Specular for a Model?

Tags: c#, xna, normals

I'm a beginner in XNA, trying my luck at a basic 3D game.

I have some very talented 3D modellers backing me, and while I have on issue importing the .fbx files (the models themselves) into my basic 3D universe in XNA, I have no idea how include the normal maps, diffuse, and specular that they've included with their models.

The normal, diffuse and specular are all in .tga image file format, and I don't know how I can add those to the drawing of my model.

Right now my code for drawing the 3D object is as follows:

```
        private void DrawObject(Model spaceStation, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in spaceStation.Meshes)
            {
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.World = world;
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;
                }
                mesh.Draw();
            }
        }
```